# Account Address search(Powered by Google) in Salesforce

Tags: search, google-map, google, address

I am trying to implement Address Search in Account Mailing and Shipping Address.

I went through the following documentation

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_maps_autocomplete.htm&type=5

and enabled

Enable Maps and Location Services (powered by Google)

checkbox.

However, the address search link is still not coming up. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your [Organization Edition](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199268&type=1), Autocomplete on Standard Addresses
 [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_maps_autocomplete.htm&type=5) says:

> Available in: **Professional**, **Enterprise**, **Performance**, and **Unlimited** editions.

Answer (score -1):

yes there is something else you need to do. Deactivate the country and territory picklist. You do that and the search bar appears.